# What phase should I expect from pauli X?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-phase-estimation

Here's an example I found that implements the phase estimation algorithm:
[image]
Here the eigenvector is initialized to the $|+\rangle$ state, which is an eigenvector of Pauli X with eigenvalue 1. The measurement result is a complete `0`. My question is what the measurement result tells us about the eigenvalue of this system? Since the qubit `q[0]` is responsible for the time-evolution, is there a way we can tell which Hamiltonian we're simulating? Is it Pauli X?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean q[1] is initialized to |+>? In the diagram it is initialized to 0. It seems like phase estimation but there is an H missing before measurement. Also what the measurement results in `0` you mean on the state |0> 100% of the times?

Comment: You should also provide the source to your example.